# Kinesis at least once semantics

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Kinesis has at least once semantics according to the documentation. I'm trying to figure out a way to ensure that duplicates are detected. If there is a duplicate record, is there a guarantee that it will come from the same shard that the original record came from? The reason I ask is this will determine whether my duplicate detection needs to be "global" in the sense that if I have multiple instances processing a stream, do I need to detect duplicates across these instances? If the duplicate came from the same shard, then this would imply that most likely the same record processor will see the duplicate(and certainly the same instance) and then my duplicate detection can be "local" to that instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decisive answer is really to **check a backing store or index** to see if the record has been inserted already (DynamoDB, Redshift, RDS etc). It is best practice to separate your datastores from your Kinesis processor instances, so that you need only to check one location. There are a few ways to do this, which might be the subject of another question.

If you are using KCL, then it handles the shards itself and you are abstracted from needing to deal with them. With KCL, **The shard your instance consumes from may change over time** so I wouldn't recommend creating a system that was dependent on an instance always receiving data from the same shard.

To answer the question though, **if a unique record is consumed from a shard once and (for whatever reason) comes again, it will be from the same shard the second time** as it's partition key will not have changed.

Note: records will normally only be received a second time when there is a failure in the delivery the first time for that record batch.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes, I am using the KCL. So I guess the instance could change though the shard remains the same. I definitely need something that keeps the latency introduced by this check in processing records to a minimum. At the moment, DynamoDB and Redis/Memcached seem like the most attractive alternatives. If you have any ideas on this, that would help.

Comment: Yes, those are good options. Depends a bit on your data size & structure, those are quite good options because of their speed & scale. If your object store is not quick to query (e.g. S3), you can consider just hosting an index of inserted record IDs (and location) in (say) dynamo. Ensure you use consistent reads if you use dynamo for this.

Comment: In the cases where I have used Kinesis, the at-least-once semantics have not been a problem because of the high scale of the data (as Kinesis is best suited for). That is to say if we have 1M log records, it wouldn't matter if a few were duplicates. Also, when you are at query time you could eliminate the duplicates from your results using a query for a distinct record id (this is the approach I typically use, rather than trying to clean the data on the way in). Of course though, there are some use cases where once-only or atomic processing is vital.